# What answers were deleted on this question that caused it to be protected by Community?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, answers, protected-questions

I'd like to know what answers were deleted on [Display screen keeps waking up when locked](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44982/display-screen-keeps-waking-up-when-locked) that caused it to be protected by Community. I know the criteria for that, but I don't have enough rep to see deleted answers, so I'd like someone to take a screenshot.

Comment: I don't think your privileges are supposed to be worked around, but the answer is as Dan says.

Comment: @MatthewRead I usually go to chat for these kinds of questions, but I posted it here because I didn't have access to chat at the time.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: @AlE. Well, those answers were deleted before I could even take a glimpse of them. The folks on SU were a lot more helpful in giving me this data on another question.

Comment: You still haven't given a compelling reason why you need to see the answers, so your request just seems voyeuristic. I concur with Dan Hulme's summary, so there's really nothing to see.

Answer (score 8):

There are four "hey, that worked for me! thanks!" answers from unregistered users.

Comment: Can you link a screenshot?